# Where did you found it - should I use "did" in the question?

Tags: questions, do-support

> Where you found it.
>
> Where **did** you found it.

In the question should I put "did"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where **did** you **find** it?

Yes, in such questions you should use the verb **do**. Note that after **do** you should use the *bare form* of the verb: **find**, not **found**. The verb **do** carries the Past Tense, being transformed into **did**, so there's no need for **find** to carry the Past Tense too. The two verbs work together, after all.

If you put this question into the Present Perfect, for example, you would need to use **have**:

> Where **have** you found it?

Both **do** and **have** are *"auxiliary verbs"*.

If you have a statement

> I **have** found it! (Present Perfect)

..and you want to transform it into a question, then you have your *auxiliary verb* ready: it's **have**:

> Where **have** you found it?

But if you have a statement

> I found it! (Past Simple)

There's no auxiliary verb in it. But to pose a question you need an *auxiliary verb*! What to do? You have to use **do**. This is called "**[do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support#In_questions)**":

> Where **did** you find it?

So it all depends on whether there's an *auxiliary verb* of some kind in the statement you want to transform into a question. If there's no such verb, use **do**.

But there's an exception: in some questions, there's no need for an auxiliary verb:

> 1. **Who** found it?
> 2. How many **people** found it?

It's because the pronoun **who** serves as the [subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(grammar)) of sentence 1, and the question words "how many" in sentence 2 refer to the subject of that sentence, which is **people**.

---

P.S. The clause

> Where you found it.

Will not work as a question. It might be included into some sentence, like this:

> Remember that golden coin? I visited the place *where you found it*, and found another.

Comment: "Where have found it" & "Where did you found it" are both incorrect. You wanted "Where have *you* found it?" and "Where did you *find* it?

Comment: @MarkWilliams - indeed! Thanks for pointing out! I wonder who upvoted me. I'll try to make it right now (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle `Where did you found it?` is correct when you're using the verb `found [to set up or establish]` which *must not be confused with* `find [to locate]`

Answer (score 1):

Where will you find it?
Where did you find it?
Where have you found it?
You can't have *where you found it* on it's own ; it would mean *the place where you found it*

Answer (score 1):

Use,

> "Where did you find it?" or "where have you found it?"

"Where you found it" refers to the **place where you actually found it.**

Eg: "Where you found it"

> Put the jacket back *where you found it.*

Comment: I've changed the answer now.

Comment: I like your explanation, simple and easy understanding.